# How to add label to flutter chart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I try charts_flutter: ^0.6.0 dependencies, 
the chart is worked very well.

but i want add label for x axis and y axis in chart.
Label like rating and numbers of entries in this picture.

```
charts.BarChart(
              _seriesData,
              animate: true,
              behaviors: [new charts.SeriesLegend()],
              animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            )
```

Comment: this picture https://i2.wp.com/tphangout.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/five.png

Comment: try including your chartview along with two other views, on on bottom and one on left

Comment: @ManojPerumarath, is flutter chart dont have that x and y axis label?

Comment: no it doesn't have it

Comment: ok, thats it.
thank you for your info.

i will use other way,
use normal text and rotated it.

Comment: that's the way to do it for now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that have not found any solution in the official doucmentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_charts/latest/

Wrap the widget with a Stack Widget and add a Text widget to it:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    AnimatedPositioned(
      // use top,bottom,left and right property to set the location and Transform.rotate to rotate the widget if needed
child : Text("Title comes here"),
duration : Duration(seconds:3),
),
charts.BarChart(
              _seriesData,
              animate: true,
              behaviors: [new charts.SeriesLegend()],
              animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            ),
]
)
```

Comment: I used this for X axis label; and set the bottom to 0. The label overlaps with the x axis markings (1, 2 , 3, etc).